# Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "P_value", value = 9.66218350888067e-05) : replacement has 1 row, data has 0

Tags: r

Can some-one help me with my code, i have a code which is calculating a lot of logistic regression at the same time. i used this code also for a lm model and then it worked quite wel, however i tried to adapt it to a glm model but it does not work anymore.

```
Output_logistic <- data.frame()
glm_output = glm(test[,1] ~ test_2[,1], family = binomial ('logit'))

Output_2 <- data.frame(R_spuared = summary(glm_output)$r.squared)
Output_2$P_value <- summary(glm_output)$coefficients[2,4]
Output_2$Variabele <- paste(colnames(test))
Output_2$Variabele_1 <- paste(colnames(test_2))
Output_2$N_NA <- length(glm_output$na.action)
Output_2$df <- paste(glm_output$df.residual)

Output_logistic <- rbind(Output_logistic,Output_2)
```

running this code gives the next error:

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "P_value", value = 9.66218350888067e-05) :
replacement has 1 row, data has 0

does anybody know what i have to adapt so that the code will work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your `Output_2` is an empty data.frame (it has no rows) because `summary(glm_output)$r.squared` does not exist, because [`glm` doesn’t report this value](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/232472/3512).

If you need the R-squared value you’ll have to calculate it yourself. But to fix the error you can simply change your code to construct the data-frame from the existing data in the summary:

```
output_2 = data.frame(
   P_value = summary(glm_output)$coefficients[2, 4],
   Variable = colnames(test),
   # … etc.
)
```

Comment: Hello Konrad, thanks for you reply, however i do quitte understand what you mean. Should i delete                                                                                                     R_spuared = summary(glm_output)$r.squared)  after data frame and delete                            output_2 before all other variables?    i tried this however i still doesn't work

Comment: 'Output_logistic <- data.frame()'


    'glm_output = glm(test[,1] ~ test_2[,1], family = binomial ('logit'))'

    
    'Output_2 <- data.frame()'
    'P_value = summary(lm_output)$coefficients[2,4]'
    'Variable = paste(colnames(test))'
    'Variabele_1 = paste(colnames(test_2))'
    'N_NA = length(lm_output$na.action)'
    'df = paste(lm_output$df.residual)'
    
    'Output_logistic <- rbind(Output_logistic,Output_2)'
   this is the new code if i understand you correct? however it does not give an output at all, so what am i doing wrong?